# Rails changing query execution order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to perform a query on first 10 records.

So, from Rails console I type:

```
Log.all.limit(10).where({"username"=>"peeyush"}).explain
```

This gives:

```
Log Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "logs".* FROM "logs"  WHERE "logs"."username" = 'peeyush' LIMIT 10
```

Clearly, LIMIT 10 happens later.

I try running:

```
Log.all.first(10).where({"username"=>"peeyush"}).explain
```

But this gives an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x0000000539acd8>
```

How should the query be performed?

Comment: After the `where` condition you should be giving `first(10)`

Comment: That does not work either! It gives an array of first 10 logs where username is peeyush.

Comment: As the query stands,that is output result right.

Comment: `Log.all.where({"username"=>"peeyush"}).first(10).explain`

Comment: This gives the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'explain' for #<Array:0x00000005ba0518>` as the return value is array of size 10. Moreover, it is not solving my purpose.

Comment: Look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-limit and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first

Comment: @Octopus-Paul I read both of them and understood that my queries will not do what I want to do. But, I am still unable to figure out how the query should be performed.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: you want to perform your query on your first  records from your table like this? `Log.all.order(:id).limit(10).where({"username"=>"peeyush"})` which translates to: `SELECT * FROM logs WHERE username='peeyush' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The translation has limit at the end whereas I want to query on first 10 records (ordered by primary key) only.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve the 1st 10 rows and then filter those 10 records by username?

Filter in ruby

```
all.first(10).find_all {|i| i.username == "peeyush" }
```

Filter on the database

```
all.where(:id => all.first(10).map {|x| x.id}, :username => "peeyush")
```

Comment: This shall work but I would like to perform filter in Database rather than doing it in Ruby code. A (not so good) method of doing that may be to apply one more where condition on id and limit id to first 10 values but I am looking for a better method.

Comment: @Peeyush just saw your updated comment, unfortunately my answer is the same but I don't see another way of doing it